# How to have PID printed to the terminal at the start of *every* process?

Tags: process, zsh

If I start an *asynchronous* ("backgrounded") process, some info, including the new process's PID, gets printed to the terminal before the process runs; for example

```
$ sleep 3 &
[1] 8217
$ 
[1]  + done       sleep 3
$
```

Is there a way to have such info (especially the PID) printed at the start of *every* process, not just those that get started asynchronously?

---

**Background**

The reason for wanting this is that, due to the peculiarities of my everyday working set up, often enough it happens that a *synchronous* long-running process fails to respond to `Ctrl-C`.  (Invariably, what makes these processes "long-running" is that they produce a lot more output than I had anticipated.)  The surest way to stop such a process is to `kill -9` it from a different window, and it would be nice to have its PID readily on hand for this.

UPDATE: In my original post I neglected to mention that `Ctrl-Z` is not an option.  (I'm working on a shell running under Emacs, so `Ctrl-Z` just suspends Emacs.)

Comment: Interesting question. With `bash` and `ksh93`, one can have a `DEBUG` trap execute before the shell runs the command on the command line, but since the command hasn't yet been executed, there's obviously no PID to output while executing the trap.

Comment: @Kusalananda: likewise, `zsh` has `preexec`, but I don't know how to get the PID of the process that's about to start...

Comment: Looking at the source code, there doesn’t appear to be anything usable to do this (between the fork, which gives you the new pid, and the exec — or rather, after the fork on the parent side). You could change `addproc` to log every new process added to the job table, which would work in the majority of cases.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but it might solve your problem anyway. You can stop and "background" a running process by pressing **Ctrl** + **Z**. That leaves you with a stopped (but still existing) process and access to the shell. Now you can run `kill %1` to kill this process (or rather the first backgrounded process, to be exact). So you do not even need to know the PID.

Comment: @StephenKitt: I updated my post to explain why I can't use `Ctrl-Z`.

Comment: @Adaephon: I updated my post to explain why I can't use `Ctrl-Z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Stephen Kitt explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358171), making zsh print the PID would be rather difficult. But you can get at the information in other ways.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process, then zsh displays its PID. And if you want to kill it, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> first, to kill it directly. If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> fails, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> for a “harder” kill (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends SIGINT, which conventionally tells a program to stop its current action and hand back control to the user; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> sends SIGQUIT, which conventionally tells a program to crash hard). You can do this even from within Emacs: in Shell mode, press `C-c C-z` to pass `C-z` to the terminal, `C-c C-c` to pass `C-c`, `C-c C-\` to pass `C-\`. In Term mode, `C-z` and `C-\` are passed directly, but you need `C-c C-c` to pass a single `C-c`.

If the process changes the terminal settings or blocks the signals, a convenient way to locate it for killing is by terminal. Find out what the terminal is; you can do this with the `tty` command inside the terminal. You might make this part of your prompt or part of the terminal title (I put it in the terminal title). Emacs doesn't display the terminal title, but it gives you access to the information by evaluating the following expression:

```
(process-tty-name (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
```

To evaluate an expression in most modes including Shell mode, type `M-:` then enter the expression. In Term mode, type `C-c M-x eval-expression RET` then enter the expression. If you use this often, bind the following command to a key in the relevant modes:

```
(defun buffer-process-tty-name ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((tty (process-tty-name (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))))
    (if (interactivep) (message "%s" tty))
    tty))
```

Once you know the terminal name, you can use e.g. `ps -t pts/42` or `pgrep -t pts/42` to list the processes that are attached to that terminal.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn’t seem to be a way of logging this information, and looking into it in more detail, it would be hard to design correctly (I initially thought it would be hard to implement too, but [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) fixed that).

I thought the implementation problem was logging the information in the right place. When a shell starts a child, it forks, and then execs the child (unless it can replace itself with the child, in which case it doesn’t fork). When it forks, the process is duplicated; one of the copies gets a return code of 0 from the `fork()` call, which indicates it’s the child, and the other gets the child’s process identifier, which indicates it’s the parent. The child inherits the parent’s file descriptors, so it can log its own pid before setting things up for `exec()`.

The design problem is choosing what to log. If we log all processes started by the shell, we end up with lots of extraneous logs, *e.g.* for processes involved in constructing the prompt! Even for “real” commands, we need to decide what to log for pipelines and other compound commands... And then for consistency we need to come up with something to log for built-in commands, or for circumstances in which the shell replaces itself with the child (although I don’t think that can happen for an interactive shell, unless you manually `exec`).

If you want to explore this further, check out `addproc()` and `printjobs()` in `jobs.c`, and `zexecve()` in `exec.c`.

Comment: So log the the PID from the child? AFAIU the child process has to handle all file descriptor setup for the to-be-started application anyway, so it shouldn't be impossible to have an fd at hand for logging?

Comment: Oh dear, yes, thanks @ilkkachu, that’s perfectly feasible.

Comment: The right place to print out the PID would be at the point of creating a process group, and then print the PGID. That way only proper jobs would be printed out, and only one per pipeline.